# Fixtures for openstack keystone

Tags: openstack, keystone

I'm creating docker container containing openstack keystone. Need to create initial data (projects, domains, users). Is it possible to do that without running keystone daemon?

Comment: I'm not aware of any mysqldump (or equivalent) that will allow you to import raw data into the DB and bypass the daemon. The only thing I'm aware of is this [bootstrap script](https://github.com/openstack/keystone/blob/master/tools/sample_data.sh) which creates a few users/tenants using the daemon itself.

Comment: Yes, I'm also aware of that script, though it requires daemon to be running. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could portentially try to take a mysql dump of the keystone database,  and then import it back into the mysql that the docker will point to. We will obviously have to replace the IP's or hostnames for the other services.